# neovim, vimscript execute keystroke from function

Tags: vimscript, neovim, functions

I am trying to execute a keystroke from function when its called. However, it does not work.

```
function SmartNERDTreeFocus()
    if expand('%') =~ 'NERD_tree.*'
        normal <C-w><C-p>
        "execute 'normal \<c-w>\<c-p>'
        "return "\<C-w>\<C-p>"
    else
        call NERDTreeFocus()
    endif
endfunction

map <silent> <C-b> :call SmartNERDTreeFocus()<CR>
```

Hitting the shortcut will open up NERDTree, but hitting it again while in NERDTree's buffer does nothing. I want it to return to the previous window (C-wC-p).

What is the correct way to execute some keystrokes from a vimscript function in neovim?

Comment: you can either use `wincmd p` or you need to put `\<C-W>\<C-P>` into *double* quotes

Comment: Both of those methods works! Thanks